# nearZeroVar function in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

when i run the following code all the variables in my dataset are removed,

```
data <- data[, -nearZeroVar(data)]
```

i am fairly new to R and my expectation was that the above code would remove the near-zero variance predictors if they are in the dataset,actually there are no near-zero variance predictors in the data,so i thought it would keep the data set as it is but it doesnt.

when running a script i wont always know if the predictors are near-zero variance predictors or not....how can i modify the code to add it into a script that checks if there are near-zero variance predictors and if none of the predictors are near-zero variance predictors then it should preserve the data set as it is.

The following code reproduces the situation.

```
library(caret)
data(GermanCredit)
# remove the near-zero var predictors
GermanCredit <- GermanCredit[, -nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)] 
# but now if i redo the above command it removes all the predictors from the data set.
GermanCredit <- GermanCredit[, -nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)]
# all predictors removed
```

There can be situations when we dont know that the data set does not contain any near-zero variance predictors.

**Update**

@LauriK,topepo(Max): One more silly question,

```
GermanCredit <- GermanCredit[, -nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)]`
```

I thought that if i write the above code as

```
GermanCredit <- GermanCredit[, -integer(0)]
```

since there is a (-) sign before `integer(0)` it should remove `integer(0)` which is nothing so it should remove nothing and preserve the data set as it is.

i know i might be missing a very basic concept here but i would like to learn.

Answer (score 5):

Save the object first:

```
nzv_cols <- nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)
if(length(nzv_cols) > 0) GermanCredit <- GermanCredit[, -nzv_cols]
```

Max

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the values in between as well, not just put them into a single line.

```
> nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)
 [1]  9 15 16 24 25 27 28 30 34 45 47 54 59
```

Means that these are near zero variance. If you remove these, then the dataset is left with 49 variables.
Now if you run the same line again, the result is different:

```
> nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)
integer(0)
```

Which means that none of the variables left are zero variance. It's an empty set. And if you subset your variables by an empty set, you get nothing left.

```
> str(GermanCredit[, -integer(0)])
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  0 variables
```

So what you should do, at first, is to not run this twice.
But even if you just run it once, it makes sense to put it inside an IF-clause:

```
if (length(nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)) > 0) {
  GermanCredit <- GermanCredit[, -nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)] 
}
```